# How did my website's localStorage got deleted for ALL users?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Last year I launched a website where users could store some personal settings.

I used localStorage.

I knew that localStorage could be deleted for security reasons or inadvertently by the user, and that's ok.

However, a couple of days ago, several of my users (including myself) reported that their settings disappeared.

What could have happened to produce this result?

**Edit:** I did not make any changes to the code! Some people's settings did not get removed!

Comment: back it up: JSON.stringify(localStorage)

Comment: did you make any code changes?

Comment: localStorage does expire in some browsers after a year. It's documented that it sticks around indefinitely, but that isn't always the case.

Comment: Did you change domains perhaps? foo.com to goo.com?